# How to correctly replace random numbers in a two-dimensional array with symbols

Tags: c#

I have created a two-dimensional array with random filling of numbers not exceeding 1. I need to replace the numbers: "0" with the character "_", and "1" with the character "*". I can't do it at all. How do I do it right..?

```
Console.Write("Enter the width of the field: ");
int q = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Enter the length of the field: ");
int w = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

int[,] myArray = new int[q, w];
Random rand = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < w; j++)
    {
        myArray[i, j] = rand.Next(2);

        if (i == 0)
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex(myArray[i, j]);
            regex.Replace("_", myArray[i, j]);
        }

        if (j == 1)
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex(myArray[i, j]);
            regex.Replace("*", myArray[i, j]);
        }

        Console.Write(myArray[i, j]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: @Soleil And what can be used? I'm just new to C#

Comment: Is this inside of couple of "for" loops?

Comment: @Floremin yes 
for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < w; j++)
                {

Comment: what does this line do: 

myArray[i, j] = rand.Next(2);

Comment: @Floremin
Randomly fills the array with numbers, but they should not exceed the digit 1. For example,
00001101
00011100

Comment: @Floremin I edited the question, laying out all the code, I hope it will be clearer this way

Comment: @foder your code do not compile you want to use a string as pattern.

Comment: @Soleil That's why I asked the question to understand exactly how to design this piece of code so that everything works

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: In addition to what @AdrianMole said, please don't submit suggested edits to vandalise the answers - the suggestions will be rejected for the same reason that your edits to your question were reverted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't replace `int` by `char` since c# is statically typed (unless you use [`dynamic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic)).

If you want to fill with random `_` and `*`, those are characters, then you want to use a character array:

```
var rand = new Random();
var charArray = new char[q, w];
for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
for (int j = 0; j < w; j++)
    charArray[i, j] = rand.Next(2) == 0 ? '_':'*';
```

If you want both int and char arrays, you need to declare both, and you may fill them together or separately:

```
var charArray = new char[q, w];
var intArray = new int[q, w];
for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
for (int j = 0; j < w; j++)
{
    intArray[i, j] = rand.Next(2);
    charArray[i, j] = intArray[i, j] == 0 ? '_':'*';
}
```

If you want to do a replace, you want to use `char` all the time:

```
var charArray = new char[q, w];
for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
for (int j = 0; j < w; j++)
    charArray[i, j] = rand.Next(2) == 0 ? '0':'1';

for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
for (int j = 0; j < w; j++)
    charArray[i, j] = charArray[i, j] == '0' ? '_':'*';
```

My piece of advice is to keep regex, which is slower, for actual complex replacements [(with wildcard, logical or, grouping, quantification)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) within strings (with double quote `"my string"`).